# Sqlalchemy Update or insert в одну транзакцию

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Есть таблица (id, name), и есть пак данных такого же формата (примерно столько же записей, сколько и в самой бд). Есть ли способ обновить или добавить (по id) все строки за один запрос?

Answer (score 3):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то insert нескольких строк можно сделать как-то так:

```
values = [
    {'id': 1, 'name': 'n1'},
    {'id': 2, 'name': 'n2'}
]
query = insert(table_instance).values(values)
session.execute(query)
```

Comment: А такой вариант обновит данные (name), если id уже существует?